# Show that if $f$ and $g$ are functions such that $f'(x)=g(x)$ and $g'(x)=-f(x)$ for all $x$ then $f^2(x)+g^2(x)$ is a constant function

Tags: calculus, functions

Show that if $f$ and $g$ are functions such that $f'(x)=g(x)$ and $g'(x)=-f(x)$ for all $x$ then $f^2(x)+g^2(x)$ is a constant function

Comment: What happens when you differentiate $f^2(x)+g^2(x)$?

Comment: @user281392: If you think it is trivial, please post a CW answer.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Community Wiki.

Comment: $f'=g\to ff'=fg;\;g'=-f'\to gg'=-fg$ derive $f^2+g^2\to 2ff'+2gg'=2fg-2fg=0$ thus $f^2+g^2=constant$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ y = g(x) $

Then $ \frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x} = -f(x) $ , $ \frac{\mathrm{d}^2 y}{\mathrm{d} x^2} = -y $

so We get $ (D^2 + 1)y = 0 $

Its solutions are only $ y = c_1\cos x + c_2 \sin x  $ except  $ y = 0 $ ($ c_1$ ,$c_2$ is constant number in $  \mathbb{C} $)

so $ g(x)^2 + g'(x)^2 = (c_1^{2} +  c_2^{2})  $

Answer (score 8):

Converting answer-comment to answer:

If $h = f^2 + g^2$, then differentiating gives $h' = 0$ and so $h$ is constant.

Comment: Is there any way to prove it using Rolle's Theorem, Mean Value Theorem or with the Consequences Rules?

Comment: @guasabito: Mean Value theorem is used to prove the statement: $f'(x) = 0 \implies f(x)$ is constant.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function $h(x)=f(x)^2 + g(x)^2$. We now show that the derivative of $h(x)$ is zero.

$h'(x)=2f(x)f'(x) + 2g(x)g'(x)$ (chain rule)

$h'(x)=2f(x)g(x) + 2g(x)g'(x)$ (substitute $f'(x) = g(x)$)

$h'(x)=2f(x)g(x) - 2g(x)f(x)$ (substitute $g'(x) = -f(x)$)

and now we can see that $h'(x)=0$ which implies $h(x)$ is constant.

Comment: Is there any way to prove it using Rolle's Theorem, Mean Value Theorem or with the Consequences Rules?

Comment: Sure. Given $x,y \in (a,b)$ with $x /neq y$ then by the mean value theorem we have $0=h'(x)=\dfrac{h(y)-h(x)}{y-x}$ which implies $h(x)=h(y)$ and so $h(x)$ is constant.